# Item with more than one value in enumerate environment

Tags: enumerate

I need to typeset a list like the following:

> 1. item 1
> 2. item 2
> 3. item 3
>
> 4-6. The same as previous ones
>
> 7. Something else

Currently, I have typeset it using `description` environment as

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
   \begin{description}
      \item[1.] item 1
      \item[2.] item 2
      \item[3.] item 3
      \item[4-6.] The same as previous ones
      \item[7.] Something else
   \end{description}
\end{document}
```

However, I wonder if this is possible using `enumerate` or something else which does the numbering itself. Is it possible to create this list using `enumerate`?

In other words, can we do some thing like this to get the desired output

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
   \begin{enumerate}
      \item item 1
      \item item 2
      \item item 3
      \item[4-6.] The same as previous ones
      \item Something else
   \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

or even using something like `\item[len=3] The same as previous ones` where by `len`, I mean the number of enumerative items after the current one.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\begin{enumerate} \item ...\end{enumerate}` does not work ? Or should `\item[4.-6.]` automatically expand `\item ...`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for your comment. I have modified it accordingly. However, I do not have a problem with this result, but just was curious if the same result is possible with `enumerate` or not? I have googled for an hour, but could not find it out, so decided to post it here.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The second case is the one I am seeking for. Is there any way for that?

Comment: To get it right: `\item[4.-6.]` should expand to `4. item 4 etc.` Or `\item[1.-6.]` should do the tedious typing? Essentially a loop?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have modified the question to reflect my idea better, sorry for ambiguous sentences.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I have changed the question statement accordingly. The reason that I am curious to get the desired output using `enumerate` although I am fulfilled with the `description` environment is the following situation. Consider I need to add a new item between items 2 and 3, then I should correct all the numbering down to the end! :( It is not a good idea, I think.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Your post was quite good, I have learned a new thing, the `for` loop. Thanks. However, the desired one is the one which combines items `4-6`, giving the label `4-6.` to that item and the next item starts at `7`. Unfortunately, you have deleted it.

Comment: @AliShakiba: I just undeleted it, but it's of no use for your question.

Comment: You can use `\addtocounter{enumi}{3}` just after `\item[4-6.] The same as previous ones`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You are right, but I am thankful for learning the new stuff, even if it is not the one I want. That's why I came to graduate school ... :D

Comment: @karlkoeller That's right. Thank you. You have give me the answer. Would you mind post it separately, so I can accept it as answer?

Comment: @AliShakiba: Well, I deleted the answer finally. It was not clear to me what you asked until the latest comments

Comment: @AliShakiba Not at all. I've answered.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sorry for wasting your precious time. English is not my first language, and I have trouble communicating my ideas even in my mother tongue. ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only way I know to achieve what you want is to increment the `enumi` counter.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
   \begin{enumerate}
      \item item 1
      \item item 2
      \item item 3
      \item[4--6.] The same as previous ones\addtocounter{enumi}{3}
      \item Something else
   \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

A version similar to Symbol 1's, but that doesn't require changing all the levels, since `\@enumctr` expands to the current counter.

The argument to `\itemx` is the number of items to unify.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{shakiba@temp}
\newcommand\itemx[1]{%
  \letcs\shakiba@save{the\@enumctr}
  \stepcounter{\@enumctr}%
  \protected@edef\shakiba@label{\csuse{the\@enumctr}--}
  \addtocounter{\@enumctr}{-1}%
  \addtocounter{\@enumctr}{#1}%
  \protected@edef\shakiba@label{\shakiba@label\csuse{the\@enumctr}}%
  \addtocounter{\@enumctr}{-1}
  \cslet{the\@enumctr}\shakiba@label
  \item
  \cslet{the\@enumctr}\shakiba@save
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item item 1
\item item 2
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item subitem 2:1
  \itemx{5}\label{X} subitem 2:2-6
  \item subitem 2:7
  \end{enumerate}
\item item 3
\itemx{3}\label{Y} The same as previous ones
\item Something else
\end{enumerate}

References: \ref{X} and \ref{Y}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

A very brute way, but no need to calculate counters yourself

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\itemx#1{
    \let\oldtheenumi\theenumi
    \let\oldtheenumii\theenumii
    \let\oldtheenumiii\theenumiii
    \let\oldtheenumiv\theenumiv
    \def\theenumi{\oldtheenumi-\addtocounter{enumi}{#1}\oldtheenumi}
    \def\theenumii{\oldtheenumii-\addtocounter{enumii}{#1}\oldtheenumii}
    \def\theenumiii{\oldtheenumiii-\addtocounter{enumiii}{#1}\oldtheenumiii}
    \def\theenumiv{\oldtheenumiv-\addtocounter{enumiv}{#1}\oldtheenumiv}
    \item
    \let\theenumi\oldtheenumi
    \let\theenumii\oldtheenumii
    \let\theenumiii\oldtheenumiii
    \let\theenumiv\oldtheenumiv
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item item 1
        \item item 2
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item subitem 2:1
            \itemx5 subitem 2:2-6
            \item subitem 2:7
        \end{enumerate}
        \item item 3
        \itemx3 The same as previous ones
        \item Something else
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```